# Query T-SQL using CASE or stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which select employee salary and I need to bring all the employees that the salary is higher that the budget. However, my problem is that some positions have the max salary as hourly rate and some annual amount. Therefore, I need to multiply the hourly rate by 2080 to get the annual salary.

So I was doing something like this but it didn't work

```
Select 
    emp_code, emp_name, emp_last_name, 
    emp_max_pay, emp_salary
    CASE 
       WHEN emp_max_pay = '##.##' THEN emp_max_pay * 2080
       ELSE   
    END
```

As you can see I have the salary and the hourly rate or annual salary:

[image]

Comment: We need a sample data and desired results as _formatted text_ please not images.

Comment: What is the data type of `emp_max_pay`?

Comment: The data type is  int

Comment: Hi sami, I cannot upload files.

Answer (score 3):

How about when max pay is less than $100 then extend it, otherwise max pay.   This assumes no hourly rate is above $100/hour.

```
CASE WHEN emp_max_pay < 100 THEN emp_max_pay * 2080  ELSE  emp_max_pay END
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to determine what the  max pay rate is. For example lets assume Max pay is 'X' then Multipy by 2080 other wise put as it is.

CASE
   WHEN emp_max_pay<'X' THEN emp_max_pay*2080 
   Else emp_max_pay
END[Salary]

Comment: Hi Yes it work I used a case statement, CASE
   WHEN emp_max_pay < 100 THEN emp_max_pay* 2080
   WHEN emp_max_pay >=10000 THEN emp_max_pay
  
 END AS MAX_PAY now I need to get those salaries that are higher to MAX_PAY but I am getting a error "Invalid Column Name"  select * from emp where MAX_PAY > SALARY